# How to keep the latest record of a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with following structure

| Date | train |
| --- | --- |
| time1 | train1 |
| time2 | train2 |
| time3 | train1 |
| time4 | train2 |

I want to create a new table and keeping only the latest record of each distinct train

| Date | train |
| --- | --- |
| time3 | train1 |
| time4 | train2 |

How should I achieve so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is for selecting the most recent rows is:

```
select t.*
from releng_retry_test_phases t
where t.date = (select max(t2.date) from releng_retry_test_phases t2 where t2.train = t.train);
```

If you actually want to modify the table and delete the older rows;

```
delete t
    from releng_retry_test_phases t join
         (select t2.train, max(date) as max_date
          from releng_retry_test_phases t2
          group by t2.train
         ) t2
         using (train)
    where t.date < t2.max_date;
```

Comment: Table prism.infrastructure.t does not exist

Comment: I tried the first query, select max(t2.date) from t t2 where t2.train = t.train, seems to only match max date not the train id date.

Comment: @Pythoner . . . `t` is an alias for your table name.  You haven't specified that in the question.

Comment: you are right, I am trying to use t as alias as well for my table but it is not working

Comment: SELECT
    releng_retry_test_phases.*
FROM releng_retry_test_phases 
WHERE
    releng_retry_test_phases.train_start_time = (
        SELECT
            MAX(t2.train_start_time)
        FROM releng_retry_test_phases t2
        WHERE
            t2.train_id = releng_retry_test_phases.train_id
    );

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to identify the rows you want:

```
select date, train
from (
  select *,
    row_number() over(partition by train order by date desc) as rn
) x
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH temp As(
    SELECT *, Row_Number() over (PARTITION BY train ORDER BY date DESC ) as 
    rowNumber FROM table 
)
SELECT date, train FROM temp WHERE rowNumber = 1
```

> You can use `row_number()` method.